# How to identify if 'span' child tag exist in 'p' tag returned by beautifulsoup?

Tags: html, python-3.x, if-statement, beautifulsoup

I am making a web **scraper** that scrapes an online novel from the index webpage and the code creates and epub file for each book of the novel. The translator of the novel has set up the webpages for the novel in 2 different formats.

The first format is a `p` tag with `span` tag inside. the `span` tag has a bunch of css in it for each section of the paragraphs, depending if its normal text or initialize.

The other format is the text in the `p` tag with no `span` tag and no css code. I have been able to use Beautifulsoup to get the portion of the code that only has the novel from the webpage. I am stuck trying to make an `if` statement that says that if `span` exists inside the chapter content, run one code, else run some other code.

I have tried using `if chapter.find('span') != []:` and `if chapter.find_all('span') != []:` from beautifulsoup, but these beautifulsoup codes return actual values, not Boolean values. I tested this by printing 'yes' or 'no' if chapter had the tag, but the output would either only be 'yes,' or only be 'no' when I checked 2 different chapters to conform they didn't have different formats.

The code I'm using:

```
    #get link for chapter 1 from index
    r = requests.get(data[1]['link'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    # if webpage announcement change 0 to 1
    chapter = soup.find_all('div', {"class" : "fr-view"})[0].find_all('p')
```

Depending on the chapter, the output is either:

```
    #chapter equals this
    [<p dir="ltr"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">Chapter 1 - title</span></p>,
    <p dir="ltr"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">stuff</span></p>,
    <p dir="ltr"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-style: italic; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">italizes</span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap"> stuff</span></p>]
```

or:

```
    #chapter equals this
    [<p>Chapter 6 - title</p>,
    <p>stuff</p>]
```

I'm trying to make and `if` statement that can read chapter and tell me if the `span` tag exits so I can execute the correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Beautiful Soup 4.7+, Beautiful Soup uses a new CSS selector library called Soup Sieve. Using `find_all` and `find` is a fine way to filter your tags conditionally, but I like to show off an alternative way that you can use to do complex filtering with CSS selectors. Soup Sieve provides a number of useful functions, and since Beautiful Soup relies on it, it should already be installed if you are using Beautiful Soup 4.7+.

In this case we just search for the `p` tags, and then utilize Soup Sieve's API directly to create a filter to compare the returned tags. Just another way to do things.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import soupsieve as sv

html = """

<p dir="ltr"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">Chapter 1 - title</span></p>,
<p dir="ltr"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">stuff</span></p>,
<p dir="ltr"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-style: italic; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">italizes</span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap"> stuff</span></p>

<p>Chapter 6 - title</p>,
<p>stuff</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
css_match = sv.compile(':has(span)')
for i in soup.select('p'):
    if css_match.match(i):
        print('found span')
    else:
        print('no span')
```

Output

```
found span
found span
found span
no span
no span
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your code snippets:

```
html = """

<p dir="ltr"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">Chapter 1 - title</span></p>,
<p dir="ltr"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">stuff</span></p>,
<p dir="ltr"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-style: italic; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap">italizes</span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap"> stuff</span></p>

<p>Chapter 6 - title</p>,
<p>stuff</p>
"""
```

You can try this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
my_p = soup.find_all('p')
for i in my_p:
    if i.find('span'):
        print('found span')
    else:
        print('no span')
```

Output:

```
found span`
found span
found span
no span
no span`
```

I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried this method but it would only output 'found spam' on both formats. I think its because `i.find('spam')` isn't a boolean function but a function that returns the string value of the `span` tag